# Is there a better way to validate this angular form?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a working solution for validating each field on keyup in a form in angularjs. I feel it can be better though. Are there any more clever ways?

The HTML:

```
     <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-keyup="validateFirstName($event) "ng-model="user.firstName"/>
      <i ng-class="firstNameValidation" class="icon placeholder-icon padding"></i>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
     <i ng-class="lastNameValidation" class="icon placeholder-icon padding"></i>
     <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
     <i ng-class="emailValidation" class="icon placeholder-icon padding"></i>
```

And in the controller i have:

```
$scope.user = {}
$scope.firstNameValidation = "ion-arrow-left-a text-danger"
$scope.lastNameValidation = "ion-arrow-left-a text-danger"
$scope.emailValidation = "ion-arrow-left-a text-danger"


$scope.validateFirstName = ($event) ->
  if $scope.user.firstName.trim().length > 2
    $scope.firstNameValidation = "ion-checkmark-circled text-success"
  else
    $scope.firstNameValidation = "ion-arrow-left-a text-danger"
```

...

And so on, a function for each field of the input validation. I feel like there is too much redundancy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The AngularJS team provide you with a small set of predefined
>     validators that you can use out of the box and I recommend you to take
>     a look at their documentation at
>     https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input
> - There's a great article over at [year of moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html) with a more in-depth
>     view and explanation on how this is done in 1.3

### The fun part

Here's a simple and dirty [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/18Iufsym6C6Ivn76AaRU?p=preview) to show you the 1.2.x way i action

Given the following template

```
<form name="myForm">
     <!-- Notice my custom validator named max-length -->
     <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" 
            max-length="20"
            ng-class="myForm.firstName.$error.maxLength ? 'ion-arrow-left-a text-danger' : 'ion-checkmark-circled text-success'" 
     />
</form>
```

**here's how you do it in Angular 1.2.x**

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .directive('maxLength', function() {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                var maxLength = parseInt(attr.maxLength);

                //For DOM -> model validation
                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                    var validity = validate(value);
                    ngModel.$setValidity('maxLength', validity);
                    return validity ? value : undefined;
                });

                //For model -> DOM validation
                ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                    var validity = validate(value);
                    ngModel.$setValidity('maxLength', validity);
                    return value;
                });

                function validate(value) {
                    return value.trim().length < maxLength;
                }
            }
        };
});
```

**and here's how it's done in Angular 1.3.x**

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .directive('maxLength', function() {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
                var maxLength = parseInt(attr.maxLength);

                ngModel.$validators.maxLength(function(value) {
                    return validate(value, maxLength);
                });

                function validate(value, maxLength) {
                   return value.trim().length < maxLength;
                }
            }
        };


});
```

### To conclude

Now, what I've shown you is one way, and the way the angular team thinks of custom validation according to their documentation but, one size doesn't fit all and there are other ways to do this validation. One such way is to make use of 3rd party modules like the one [Marcel-Stör mentioned in his answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252558/665868)

Best of luck to you on your road to mastering custom validation in angularjs :)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, yeah i would imagine i can make my code simpler by using a combination of some of the built in validators. Your answer points me in the right direction. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

It may be a matter of style or preference but I suggest you give [valdr](http://netceteragroup.github.io/valdr/) a try. I'm quite convinced it offers the features you're looking for - particularly if redundancy bothers you.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, valdr looks great, and i would definitely use it for web apps, but in a mobile app, the validation errors and feedback need to somehow be shown in the input itself, not below it. Unless i missed it valdr does not let you configure that, for instance to highlight an icon inside an input.

Comment: Hhmm, not sure I understand...Rather than rendering the [configureable message template](https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr#message-template) you'd need valdr to set CSS classes on the input field itself? That's built-in, the [demo](http://netceteragroup.github.io/valdr/) shows that if you enter an invalid email address the input field has the CSS classes `ng-invalid ng-invalid-valdr-email ng-invalid-valdr`. If it's valid they'd be `ng-valid-valdr-email ng-valid ng-valid-valdr`. What's missing is that the template shouldn't be rendered at all?